# Thymeleaf - How to compare string with request parameter in html in Thymeleaf tag "th:if"?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How to compare string with request parameter in html in Thymeleaf tag "th:if" ?
right now i am using this

```
<div class="error" th:if="${param.error == 'badCredentialsException'}" th:with="errorMsg=#{login.badCredentials}">                      
     <p class="errorMsg"><span th:text="${errorMsg}"></span></p>
</div>
```

But no luck, it is not working.

Comment: Are you sure ${param.error} has the correct value?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's not working because `param.error` is array of strings. You must retrieve first element of array (`param.error[0]`) to get first value of parameter (see [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#web-context-namespaces-for-requestsession-attributes-etc.)). Besides that you can access request parameter via Web context object method `#httpServletRequest.getParameter` that returns first value when parameter is multivalued (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)).

1. Usage of Web context namespaces for request attributes

   ```
   <div class="error" th:if="${param.error[0] == 'badCredentialsException'}" th:with="errorMsg=#{login.badCredentials}">                      
       <p class="errorMsg"><span th:text="${errorMsg}"></span></p>
   </div>
   ```
2. Usage of Web context object

   ```
   <div class="error" th:if="${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('error') == 'badCredentialsException'}" th:with="errorMsg=#{login.badCredentials}">                      
       <p class="errorMsg"><span th:text="${errorMsg}"></span></p>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Important note about this: ${param.error[0]} will cause SpelEvaluationException Cannot index into a null value if there will be no such request parameter. It depends on you context, but you may want check ${param.containsKey('error')} before.

Answer (score 8):

With Thymeleaf 3, I normally use [`#request`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html#request-parameters) (a short form of `#httpservletrequest`) and [`#strings.equals()`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#strings) for that, which will look like this:

```
<div th:if="${#strings.equals(#request.getParameter('error'), 'badCredentialsException')}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me

#strings.equals(string1, string2)

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61361448/2227743).