# I have trouble with th:if in spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

So I started study java + Spring and i have a problem with "th:if". When i want to print on localhost:8080/car YearOfProduction = 2000 and I use 
th:info="${info} == '2000'" in my templates  it's nothing happens but when i remove th:info="${info} == '2000'" everything works ok, it means when i write for example 1999 in YearOfProduction my app print on localhost year which i wrote.

My controller class:

@Controller
public class CarCotnroller {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/car", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String carPost(@ModelAttribute("carForm") CarForm form, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("info", "Rok produkcji samochodu to: " + form.getYearOfProduction());

    return "cars";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/car", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String carPost(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("carForm", new CarForm());
    return "car";
}
```

}

My Form class:

```
public class CarForm {

private String carname;
private String yearOfProduction;

public CarForm(String carname, String yearOfProduction) {
    this.carname = carname;
    this.yearOfProduction = yearOfProduction;
}

public CarForm() {

}

public String getCarname() {
    return carname;
}

public void setCarname(String carname) {
    this.carname = carname;
}

public String getYearOfProduction() {
    return yearOfProduction;
}

public void setYearOfProduction(String yearOfProduction) {
    this.yearOfProduction = yearOfProduction;
}
```

}

and my templates:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>

    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<center><span th:if="${info} == '2000'" th:text="${info}"></span></center>
</br></br>
<form th:action="@{/car}" method="post" th:object="${carForm}">
    Car name: <input type="text" th:field="*{carname}">
    <p></p>
    year of production: <input type="text" th:field="*{yearOfProduction}">
    <p></p>

    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `${info}` a `String` or an `int`? What happens if you try `th:if="${info == 2000}"`

Comment: nothing happens. ${info} is a String

Comment: Do you only want it to print `${info}` if it is `2000`? Why don't you just write `<span>2000</span>`? I don't understand the purpose of the `th:if`.

Comment: When i changed ${info} on int and try other comparisons for example:  th:if="${info gt 2000}"    and    th:if="${info &gt; 2000}" I gets such errors: 
 "Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "info gt 2000" (template: "car" - line 9, col 15)" and "Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "info > 2000" (template: "car" - line 9, col 15)".....

Comment: because i learn it and i wanna know what i'm doing wrong :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf - How to compare string with request parameter in html in Thymeleaf tag "th:if"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243277/thymeleaf-how-to-compare-string-with-request-parameter-in-html-in-thymeleaf-ta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why it isn't work but i make it an another way I wrote in CarController:

```
model.addAttribute("info", form.getYearOfProduction() == 2000 ? form.getYearOfProduction(): "Error");
```

and it's work great. Thank you for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Strings](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#strings) utils:

```
<span th:if="${#strings.equals(info, '2000')}" th:text="${info}"></span>
```

Comment: your code looks ok, but it still don't work and I don't know why.. ;/

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to print any info based on any condition why don't you try something like:

```html
<span th:text="${info} == '2000' ? 'something' : 'something else'"></span>
```

Or if you really need the `if` tag, then something like:

```html
<span th:if="${info} == '2000'>Something</span><span th:if="not ${info} == '2000'">Something else</span>
```

You might want to take a quick reading on [Thymeleaf comparators and equality](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#comparators-and-equality)

Comment: your code looks ok too, but it still don't work and I don't know why.. ;/